# get_text() return empty value. I want to convert it to None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm handling data using beautifulsoup.

Now I got a problem.

my code is below

```
elif '임차인' and '점유부분' in table.get_text(): #임차인 현황
    print(table)
    for renters in table.findAll('tr')[1::]:
        # print(renters)
        for renter_values in renters.findAll('td', ({'class':'center'})):
            print("It is \n" + renter_values.get_text())
            registration_of_businessman = renters.findAll('td', ({'class': 'left'}))[0]
            etc = renters.findAll('td', ({'class': 'left'}))[1]
            rental_fee = renters.find('td', ({'class': 'money'}))
```

[image]

above is the partial output. You can see the empty value Below the 4th 'It is'

You can get table source in here. http://blog.naver.com/khm2963/220987221959

How can I solve this??

Comment: If you want an empty string converted to `None`, you could use `(renter_values.get_text() or None)`.

Comment: The `'임차인' and` part of your expression is redundant. It can be removed without changing the meaning of the expression. If you wanted to test if both strings are present, you need to use a different expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I add 'or None' in my code like renter_values.get_text().strip() or None.
But it return empty string. why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want. You want the None or the string converted to a string 'None'? Here is a example:

```
elif '임차인' and '점유부분' in table.get_text(): #임차인 현황
    print(table)
    for renters in table.findAll('tr')[1::]:
        # print(renters)
        for renter_values in renters.findAll('td', ({'class':'center'})):
            return_value = renter_values.get_text()
            if return_value:
                print("It is \n" + return_value)
            registration_of_businessman = renters.findAll('td', ({'class': 'left'}))[0]
            etc = renters.findAll('td', ({'class': 'left'}))[1]
            rental_fee = renters.find('td', ({'class': 'money'}))
```

While inspecting the beautifulSoup get_text method I found that this method will return a `''` if there where no catched_values by this method. It uses a `.join()` function on a string seperator. So that the method returns a empty string is correct. If you really need the `None` assignment then add a line like: `return_value = return_value if len(return_value) > 0 else None` under the return_value assignment.

The code below:

```
def get_text(self, separator=u"", strip=False, types=(NavigableString, CData)):
    """
    Get all child strings, concatenated using the given separator.
    """
    return separator.join([s for s in self._all_strings(
                strip, types=types)])
```

Comment: I wanna convert empty string to None. Thanks for your answer. above doesn't work

Comment: No problem :) You mean my code doesn't work (because it is above) or that the other answers didn't work?

Comment: In python ``None`` will give you a ``False`` statement in conditions. Empty strings like ``''`` also give you a ``False`` statement. If you  really need the ``None`` you can add a line beneath the return_value assignment: ``return_value = return_value if len(return_value) > 0 else None``

Comment: Inspecting the beautifulSoup get_text() method you can see that the method returns a ``''`` if there where no catch valuse, because it uses a .join function on a string ``separator``. I'll add the method in the answer

Comment: Thanks~~ Too late choice because I was occupied with my work. You are great!! Have a nice day~~

Comment: No problem, you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Empty value appear because the space is found in the leaf-tag.

You have to make a filter on the 'white-space only string', as follow

```
for renter_values in renters.findAll('td', ({'class':'center'})):
    if renter_values.get_text().strip():
        print("It is \n" + renter_values.get_text())
```